# Chrome and session data lost

Tags: php, session, cookies, kohana

I have a problem with Chrome and sessions...
I'm using Kohana Framework for PHP.

I manage sessions with the Auth module using the native driver.
My problem is that when i login with Chrome everything is fine, it creates the cookie and I can see the session data if I do `var_dump($_SESSION)` or `var_dump(Session::instance())`, but when I go to another page my session data is lost.

I can see the cookie in the developer tools and I see that it doesn't change it's value, but if I do `var_dump($_SESSION)` or `var_dump(Session::instance)` it has lost the session data.

I changed the cookie lifetime, the `$salt`, y defined the domain and I tested with `Cookie::$domain = FALSE`, `Cookie::$domain = NULL`, `Cookie::$domain = '.localhost'`, `Cookie::$domain = '.ipadress'` and without `Cookie::$domain`.... and I can't get it to work.

Everything works as expected in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved.
It was the missing favicon problem... (Chrome looks for a favicon and if it doesn't find it, the session data dissapears). 
The solution was to put a favicon in the root folder of the project.
Strange problem... but finally solved.

Comment: Just throwing in that this `favicon` issue is not restricted to PHP apps w/ Chrome. I just encountered this problem with a ColdFusion application where Chrome lost session, but no other browser did. Adding a `favicon` fixed it as described.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it could also be a domain Issue, if you can, try to reach you site with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.. If you have multiple sites and you have defined them in the hosts file like this:

```
site1.local localhost
...
```

try to change it to the local IP

```
site1.local 127.0.0.1
...
```

It's a try worth ;)

Comment: Thank you for the idea... I tried and it doesn't work.... do you have another idea to try? thanks...

Comment: hmm, no sorry.. try to google.. it seems to be a real issue with "chrome session"